# Flutter Web getting stuck at Http request when hosted - Working fine locally

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I've built my first flutter for web app. Here is my relevant code:

```
  String status='Starting...';

  CPConstructor () {
    downloadMenu();
  }

  void changeStatus ( String status) {
      this.status = status;
      notifyListeners();
  }

  void downloadMenu () async {
    try {
      var getRestDetailsURL = "some Api URL";
      var getMenuDataURL = 'some Api URL';
      changeStatus("Connecting...");
      http.Response response1 = await http.post(getRestDetailsURL, body: {'res_key': resKey, 'auth_key': authKey}).timeout(Duration(seconds: 1), onTimeout: (){
        changeStatus("Connection timeout...\n Please refresh the page.");
        return;
      });
      changeStatus("Downloading latest menu..."); // Getting STUCK here
      http.Response response2 = await http.post(getMenuDataURL, body: {'res_key': resKey, 'auth_key': authKey}).timeout(Duration(seconds: 1),onTimeout: (){
        changeStatus("Please refresh the page...");
        return;
      });
       debugPrint('Response status: ${response1.statusCode}');
       // Sometimes throwing exception for undefined object for response1??????
       debugPrint('Response body: ${response1.body}', wrapWidth:1024);
       debugPrint('Response status: ${response2.statusCode}');
       debugPrint('Response body: ${response2.body}', wrapWidth:1024);
      
      dataLoaded = true;
      notifyListeners();
      trialCounter=0;
      return;
    } on TimeoutException catch(e){
      print(e);
      trialCounter++;
      if (trialCounter<3) downloadMenu();
      return;
    }
  }
```

**PROBLEM**
It works fine on localhost. But when I depoloy to firebase hosting, it is getting stuck at
`http.Response response2 = await http.post(getMenuDataURL, body...`

**AND**
Sometimes it throws exception for response1 as an undefined object at the following statement:

```
debugPrint('Response status: ${response1.statusCode}');
```

Not sure what is happening and need some help please.

Comment: timeout of 1 second in too less for hosted site. may be it works fine locally but it may cause error when hosted.

Comment: Made it 5 from 1, still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the error finally using debug console.
I was making at http request from an Https hosting so it was mixed content error which the browser was blocking. For testing I have hosted the website on a http server and it works just fine!